# how to ensure that square brackets [ ] surround the contents of the node?

Tags: json, xml, xslt, biztalk, azure-logic-apps

**How do you ensure that the transform for a specific field will always be inside of an array?**

My map is converting an XML payload to another XML payload.

```
Field1 --> use
Field2 --> system
Field3 --> value
```

Here's the "right" side schema, with `identifier` as the parent node:

[image]

After transformation, the XML result is:

```
<ns0:identifier>
    <ns0:use>a</ns0:use>
    <ns0:system>b</ns0:system>
    <ns0:value>c</ns0:value>
</ns0:identifier>
```

If I convert this to json:

```
{
  identifier: {"use":"a", "system":"b", "value":"c"}
}
```

However, the result I need is for the contents of `identifier` to be enclosed inside of an array, `[]`:

```
{
  identifier: [{"use":"a", "system":"b", "value":"c"}]
}
```

**How do I ensure that this payload will always be inside of an array?**

Per this [resource](https://azurebiztalkread.wordpress.com/2018/10/06/biztalk-xml-to-json-array-conversion/):

[image]

I've tried this solution; however changing the min/max to 1, didn't seem to make any difference in the output:

[image]

Comment: As Johns has said in the comments below his answer. What version of BizTalk are you using?

Answer (score 2):

For BizTalk Server 2013 R2 and higher:

**Set the Max Occurs to * (Unbounded)**

For BizTalk Server 2013 and lower using JSON.Net in a Pipeline Component:

You have to add the json:Array attribute to the Element on the Xml Schema so the JSON serializer will always treat an object as an Array.

The only value us true: json:Array='true'

Details here: [Convert XML to JSON and force array](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJsonForceArray.htm)

Comment: thanks so much i've attempted to do that here: https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-to-json-converter.html with the following payload:  `<root>
    <identifier json:Array='true'>
        <use>usual</use>
        <system>codes</system>
        <value>AppointmentID_0</value>
    </identifier>   
</root>` but got this message: `Unable to parse any XML input. The prefix "json" for attribute "json:Array" associated with an element type "identifier" is not bound.

`

Comment: OH the schema, let me try that

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' The Question is tagged BizTalk so this Answer is for BizTalk.  I have not idea what freeformatter is or how it works.  They may have a different notation.

Comment: `namespace prefix json is not defined`

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' You have to import the newtonsoft schema which defines the Array attribute the serializer recognizes.

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Hold on, what version of BizTalk are you using?  It changed from pre-2013 to 2016.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not control how the XML conversion happens then you just need to check to see if the value is already an array or not and change it if it is not an Array.

Let's say that you get your result back in a variable called `res`.

```
res = {identifier: {"use":"a", "system":"b", "value":"c"}};
```

You can then use code like this to make sure it is what you want:

```js
let res = {
  identifier: {
    "use": "a",
    "system": "b",
    "value":"c"
  }
};

console.log(res);
console.log('---------------------------');
if(!Array.isArray(res.identifier)) {
  res.identifier = [res.identifier];
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: rather than mutate the result of the transformation, i'd like to be able to declaritively specify this behavior

Comment: Again, this is something to do if you can't change the way the data is returned to you.